# Prove that there is no fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, whereby $f(x):=(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1})/2$ with $x \in \mathbb R$.

Show that $f$ fulfils: $\forall x, y \in \mathbb R$ with $x \neq y$

$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$, whereby $d(x,y):=|x-y|$

(First question they have not mentioned the metric $d$ used, so how can I prove this? Must I just conclude that we are using the euclidean norm?)

Then show that $f$ does not have a single fixed point. (I'm assuming it's easiest to prove this via contradiction).

Comment: What's your $d$?

Comment: That's the issue, it has not been given, should I just assume we are using $|.|$?

Comment: If no specific $d$ is mentioned, it's a pretty safe assumption they mean the standard metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. It is, after all, the _standard_ metric. That being said, they ought to have been specific.

Comment: It is better that you tell us what is $d$. Of course we will guess that it's $|\cdot|$, but why don't you just write $|\cdot|$ instead?

Comment: @JohnMa I think the point is that the _original problem_ doesn't say which $d$ it is, so he _wants our help_ figuring out which one to use. At least as a first step.

Comment: But how can we be sure what is $d$, @Arthur?

Comment: @JohnMa: We can't, but the OP doesn't know and our guesses are _more educated_ than what he can come up with himself. Are you somehow trying to provoke the OP into admitting that he has just typed a homework exercise that he doesn't fully understand into the question box? That's sort of pointless; we _can see_ that's what he's done.

Comment: Yes, @HenningMakholm I am trying to tell the OP that knowing the definition of a problem is essential to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $d$ is the euclidean metric.

We have $f'(x) = \frac12\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$ so by the mean value theorem there exists $c$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le |f'(c)||x-y| < |x-y|$$

because for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ holds

$$|f'(c)| \le \frac12\left(1 + \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) < \frac12(1+1) = 1$$

However, $f$ does not have a fixed point:

$$x = f(x) = \frac12\left(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right) \implies x = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$$

which is impossible because $|x| < \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.